# Count text with conditional if not working on Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula, countif

I'm trying to count some text depending on if a cell say Yes or No. So basically I have the formula that work for count the text or any value different than empty that is this one:

```
=COUNTIF(G2:G14,"?*")+COUNT(G2:G14)
```

The problem comes when I try to use the IF with this formula:

```
=IF(D2="Yes", COUNTIF(J4:GI4,"?*")+COUNT(J4:GI4))")"
```

This is the image of the sheet and the formulas:

[image]

Any help or suggestion to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Omit last `")"` in your formula. That is causing error. Try-

```
=IF(D2="Yes", COUNTIF(J4:GI4,"?*")+COUNT(J4:GI4),"")
```